# What is the amount of Power required to maintain a flywheel at an angular velocity $\omega$ rad\sec of mass $M$ kg and Radius $R$ m?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, friction

What is the amount of Power required to maintain a flywheel at an angular velocity W rad\sec of mass M kg and Radius R m ?[image]

Comment: In which all factors the angular velocity of a flywheel depends.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no friction the energy you put in initially will be conserved and the flywheel will rotate forever, then you don't need to put in any extra power to keep it running.